# How can I perfect this game for Wolfram Demonstration publication?

Tags: dynamic, number-representation, eventhandler, data-types

When the messages change the window inactivates, and when I try to host an interactive CDF on my site it turns red and says something about numbers having to be scaled or offset. Any help?

> I'm specifically trying to figure out why the window deactivates when the variable `message` is changed dynamically.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

```
bound = {{2, -1}, {2, 5}, {1, 0}, {3, 0}, {0, 1}, {4, 1}, {0, 2}, {4, 
   2}, {-1, 3}, {5, 3}, {-1, 4}, {5, 4}, {-1, 5}, {5, 5}, {0, 6}, {1, 
   6}, {3, 6}, {4, 6}}

DynamicModule[
 {
  pos1 = {x1, y1} = {2, 2}, pos2 = {x2, y2} = {2, 4}, 
  pos3 = {x3, y3} = {2, 0},
  message = "Start",
  DotT = {a2, b2} = {x2, (y2 - 0.51)}, 
  DotL = {a1, b1} = {x1, (y1 + 0.51)}, 
  DotB = {a3, b3} = {x3, (y3 + 0.51)},
  Switch = True, Stick = False
  },
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[
   Magnify[
    Graphics[
     {
      Opacity[0.9],
      Blue, {Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[{pos2, DotT}]},
      Green, {Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[{pos1, DotL}]},
      Blue, {Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[{pos3, DotB}]},
      Style[Text[message, {2, 5}], FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Small, 
       Gray, FontSize -> 15],
      Gray, Disk[{0, 5}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{0, 4}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{0, 3}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{1, 5}, .1],
      Black, Disk[{1, 4}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{1, 3}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{3, 5}, .1],
      Black, Disk[{3, 4}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{3, 3}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{4, 5}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{4, 4}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{4, 3}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{1, 1}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{2, 1}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{3, 1}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{1, 2}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{2, 2}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{3, 2}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{2, 0}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{2, 3}, .1],
      Gray, Disk[{2, 4}, .1],
      Green, Disk[pos1, .25],
      Style[Text[L, pos1], FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Large, White],
      Blue, Disk[pos2, .25],
      Style[Text[T, pos2], FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Large, White],
      Blue, Disk[pos3, .25],
      Style[Text[B, pos3], FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Large, White]
      }
     ]
    ]
   ],
  {
   "UpArrowKeyDown" :> {
     message = "", Switch = True, Stick = False,
     If[(**)
      {x1, y1 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1} || {x1, y1 + 1} == {x2, y2} || {x1,
          y1 + 1} == {x3, y3} || {x3, y3 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1} || {x3, 
         y3 + 1} == {x2, y2},
      {
       Which[
        {x3, y3 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1},
        {pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 + 1}}, 
         pos2 = pos2, pos3 = pos3},
        {x3, y3 + 1} == {x2, y2},
        {pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 + 1}}, 
         pos2 = pos2, pos3 = pos3},
        {x1, y1 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
         message = "Gameover",
         DotT = {2, (4 - .51)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .51)}, 
         DotB = {2, (0 + .51)},
         Switch = False
         },
        {x1, y1 + 1} == {x2, y2},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}
         },
        {x1, y1 + 1} == {x3, y3},
        {
         Which[
          Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 + 1}}] == {{x3, y3 + 1}},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}
           },
          {x3, y3 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
           message = "Gameover",
           DotT = {2, (4 - .51)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .51)}, 
           DotB = {2, (0 + .51)},
           Switch = False
           },
          Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 + 1}}] != {{x3, y3 + 1}},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 + 1}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2 - 1}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3 + 1}}
           }
          ]
         }
        ]
       },
      {
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x1, y1 + 1}}] == {{x1, y1 + 1}},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}}, Stick = True
         },
        pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 + 1}}
        ],
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x2, y2 - 1}}] == {{x2, y2 - 1}},
        pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
        If[
         Stick == True,
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2 - 1}}
         ]
        ],
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 + 1}}] == {{x3, y3 + 1}},
        pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
        If[
         Stick == True,
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3 + 1}}
         ]
        ]
       }
      ],
     If[
      Switch == True,
      {
       DotT = {a2 = x2, b2 = y2 - .51}, 
       DotL = {a1 = x1, b1 = y1 + .51}, DotB = {a3 = x3, b3 = y3 + .51}
       }
      ],
     Switch = True,
     If[
      {x2, y2} == {1, 4} && {x3, y3} == {3, 4} || {x3, y3} == {1, 
          4} && {x2, y2} == {3, 4},
      message = "Win"
      ]
     },
   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> {
     message = "", Switch = True, Stick = False,
     If[(**)
      {x1, y1 - 1} == {x2, y2 + 1} || {x1, y1 - 1} == {x2, y2} || {x1,
          y1 - 1} == {x3, y3} || {x3, y3 - 1} == {x2, y2 + 1} || {x3, 
         y3 - 1} == {x2, y2},
      {
       Which[
        {x3, y3 - 1} == {x2, y2 + 1},
        {pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 - 1}}, 
         pos2 = pos2, pos3 = pos3},
        {x3, y3 - 1} == {x2, y2},
        {pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 - 1}}, 
         pos2 = pos2, pos3 = pos3},
        {x1, y1 - 1} == {x2, y2 + 1},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
         message = "Gameover",
         DotT = {2, (4 - .51)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .51)}, 
         DotB = {2, (0 + .51)},
         Switch = False
         },
        {x1, y1 - 1} == {x2, y2},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}
         },
        {x1, y1 - 1} == {x3, y3},
        {
         Which[
          Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 - 1}}] == {{x3, y3 - 1}},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}
           },
          {x3, y3 - 1} == {x2, y2 + 1},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
           message = "Gameover",
           DotT = {2, (4 - .51)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .51)}, 
           DotB = {2, (0 + .51)},
           Switch = False
           },
          Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 - 1}}] != {{x3, y3 - 1}},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 - 1}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2 + 1}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3 - 1}}
           }
          ]
         }
        ]
       },
      {
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x1, y1 - 1}}] == {{x1, y1 - 1}},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}}, Stick = True
         },
        pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 - 1}}
        ],
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x2, y2 + 1}}] == {{x2, y2 + 1}},
        pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
        If[
         Stick == True,
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2 + 1}}
         ]
        ],
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 - 1}}] == {{x3, y3 - 1}},
        pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
        If[
         Stick == True,
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3 - 1}}
         ]
        ]
       }
      ],
     If[
      Switch == True,
      {
       DotT = {a2 = x2, b2 = y2 + .51}, 
       DotL = {a1 = x1, b1 = y1 - .51}, DotB = {a3 = x3, b3 = y3 - .51}
       }
      ],
     Switch = True,
     If[
      {x2, y2} == {1, 4} && {x3, y3} == {3, 4} || {x3, y3} == {1, 
          4} && {x2, y2} == {3, 4},
      message = "Win"
      ]
     },
   "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> {
     message = "", Switch = True, Stick = False,
     If[(**)
      {x1 - 1, y1} == {x2 + 1, y2} || {x1 - 1, y1} == {x2, 
         y2} || {x1 - 1, y1} == {x3, y3} || {x3 - 1, y3} == {x2 + 1, 
         y2} || {x3 - 1, y3} == {x2, y2},
      {
       Which[
        {x3 - 1, y3} == {x2 + 1, y2},
        {pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1 - 1, y1 = y1}}, 
         pos2 = pos2, pos3 = pos3},
        {x3 - 1, y3} == {x2, y2}, {pos1 = 
          pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1 - 1, y1 = y1}}, pos2 = pos2, 
         pos3 = pos3},
        {x1 - 1, y1} == {x2 + 1, y2},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
         message = "Gameover",
         DotT = {2, (4 - .51)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .51)}, 
         DotB = {2, (0 + .51)},
         Switch = False
         },
        {x1 - 1, y1} == {x2, y2},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}
         },
        {x1 - 1, y1} == {x3, y3},
        {
         Which[
          Intersection[bound, {{x3 - 1, y3}}] == {{x3 - 1, y3}},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}
           },
          {x3 - 1, y3} == {x2 + 1, y2},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
           message = "Gameover",
           DotT = {2, (4 - .51)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .51)}, 
           DotB = {2, (0 + .51)},
           Switch = False
           },
          Intersection[bound, {{x3 - 1, y3}}] != {{x3 - 1, y3}},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1 - 1, y1 = y1}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2 + 1, y2 = y2}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3 - 1, y3 = y3}}
           }
          ]
         }
        ]
       },
      {
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x1 - 1, y1}}] == {{x1 - 1, y1}},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
         Stick = True
         },
        pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1 - 1, y1 = y1}}
        ],
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x2 + 1, y2}}] == {{x2 + 1, y2}},
        pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
        If[
         Stick == True,
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2 + 1, y2 = y2}}
         ]
        ],
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x3 - 1, y3}}] == {{x3 - 1, y3}},
        pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
        If[
         Stick == True,
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3 - 1, y3 = y3}}
         ]
        ]
       }
      ],
     If[
      Switch == True,
      {
       DotT = {a2 = x2 + .51, b2 = y2}, 
       DotL = {a1 = x1 - .51, b1 = y1}, DotB = {a3 = x3 - .51, b3 = y3}
       }
      ],
     Switch = True,
     If[
      {x2, y2} == {1, 4} && {x3, y3} == {3, 4} || {x3, y3} == {1, 
          4} && {x2, y2} == {3, 4},
      message = "Win"
      ]
     },
   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> {
     message = "", Switch = True, Stick = False,
     If[(**)
      {x1 + 1, y1} == {x2 - 1, y2} || {x1 + 1, y1} == {x2, 
         y2} || {x1 + 1, y1} == {x3, y3} || {x3 + 1, y3} == {x2 - 1, 
         y2} || {x3 + 1, y3} == {x2, y2},
      {
       Which[
        {x3 + 1, y3} == {x2 - 1, y2},
        {pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1 + 1, y1 = y1}}, 
         pos2 = pos2, pos3 = pos3},
        {x3 + 1, y3} == {x2, y2},
        {pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1 + 1, y1 = y1}}, 
         pos2 = pos2, pos3 = pos3},
        {x1 + 1, y1} == {x2 - 1, y2},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
         message = "Gameover",
         DotT = {2, (4 - .51)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .51)}, 
         DotB = {2, (0 + .51)},
         Switch = False
         },
        {x1 + 1, y1} == {x2, y2},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}
         },
        {x1 + 1, y1} == {x3, y3},
        {
         Which[
          Intersection[bound, {{x3 + 1, y3}}] == {{x3 + 1, y3}},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}
           },
          {x3 + 1, y3} == {x2 - 1, y2},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
           message = "Gameover",
           DotT = {2, (4 - .51)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .51)}, 
           DotB = {2, (0 + .51)},
           Switch = False
           },
          Intersection[bound, {{x3 + 1, y3}}] != {{x3 + 1, y3}},
          {
           pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1 + 1, y1 = y1}},
           pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2 - 1, y2 = y2}},
           pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3 + 1, y3 = y3}}
           }
          ]
         }
        ]
       },
      {
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x1 + 1, y1}}] == {{x1 + 1, y1}},
        {
         pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
         Stick = True
         },
        pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1 + 1, y1 = y1}}
        ],
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x2 - 1, y2}}] == {{x2 - 1, y2}},
        pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
        If[
         Stick == True,
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
         pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2 - 1, y2 = y2}}
         ]
        ],
       If[(*Test if next move out of bound.*)
        Intersection[bound, {{x3 + 1, y3}}] == {{x3 + 1, y3}},
        pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
        If[
         Stick == True,
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
         pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3 + 1, y3 = y3}}
         ]
        ]
       }
      ],
     If[
      Switch == True,
      {
       DotT = {a2 = x2 - .51, b2 = y2}, 
       DotL = {a1 = x1 + .51, b1 = y1}, 
       DotB = {a3 = x3 + .51, b3 = y3}}
      ],
     Switch = True,
     If[
      {x2, y2} == {1, 4} && {x3, y3} == {3, 4} || {x3, y3} == {1, 
          4} && {x2, y2} == {3, 4},
      message = "Win"
      ]
     }
   }
  ]
 ]
```

---

I made a cute one [here](http://pastebin.com/S3kwPc75).

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Comment: I want to publish the game on Wolfram Demonstrations.

Comment: To play, you have to click the window, then use only the arrow keys to move the green (L) around so that the two blue dots simultaneously land on the two black dots separately. You have to reclick the window if the message changes to continue playing.

Comment: An example of a win is the following move series: RDUUULLDDDRU Where (R)ight, (U)p, (L)eft, and (D)own.

Comment: 1) You need to narrow down your problem a lot more before we can start helping. Unfortunately I don't have the time to wade through a few pages of code without even knowing what exactly is wrong. 2) I tried copying your of code and executing it, but all I get is a static grid. No amount of R, U, L, D gets me anywhere.

Comment: Did you initialize 'bound' as a variable? Did you click the 'static grid' and *then* press your arrow keys? I have an interactive game in my notebook, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I did initialize `bound` from your code. I realized that I have to click the grid twice (but not double click it), then it will respond to input. After the first input, though, it will get deselected, and I have to select it again; after that, it doesn't happen any more and I can press multiple arrow buttons in a row. I was then able to reproduce your win strategy correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I can't get why it's deselecting... Really irritating because, as you can see, explaining how to do it with this flaw is more complicated.

Comment: The hidden rules are from the following game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7CNOnqAaCw&index=14&list=PLkBK2hrDcB5ucqVzu5cMgRNqL4sBUj7op#t=9m49s

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as this is not a debugging service. Please reduce your code to the **minimal** example in which your issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Are you using Initialization or SaveDefinitions, how CDF can know about `bounds` variable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.